# How to import a character into Unity with textures from BI?

Tags: texturing, materials, export, texture-baking, unity

So this has really got me stuck. I have created this character model with a simple rig below.

[image]

However when I put the viewport into material view you can see it goes black.

I've used the baked AO as a texture to which I bound to a material, you can see on the right side that it looks all linked, but it still stays black.

(I can't do this in cycles because the texture involves Ambient Occlusion which I baked.)

[image]

When I try to import my model and rig into Unity there is no texture at all on the model.

I'm really confused and would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any actual texture added to the material? Blender Internal can show the texture in the Texture shading mode without any texture assigned to the mesh (if all the mesh was selected when you choosed texture in the UV editor) This however won't make any difference for Unity as it doesn't know Blender's materials. To import texture there first save it as .png or any other suitable format (not sure Unity understands .psd) and import it as an asset, then apply to material there (not related to Blender)

Comment: I know somebodies still not getting the idea, here is the best solution for exporting from blender to unity with materials:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gjld8C482KA

Answer (score 1):

Unity does not normally import textures along with meshes since this is in fact a poor design choice on your part, it's best to separate mesh from texture. [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectBlender.html) is a document detailing what Unity can import from Blender with the .blend files.

[Here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/983465/importing-blender-model-with-textures-unity-5.html) is a post detailing the process of importing objects from Blender to Unity.

Brief step by step:

- Generate a UV map for your mesh
- Make the texture for the object
- Save your texture file to a separate file. .jpg should do, or .png for textures with a lot of similar colors/few colors overall.
- Save it as either a .blend or .fbx file to import to Unity
- Import your object to Unity
- Browse to find your object
- Find your material options for your mesh, and drag your texture file from the file viewer into the texture/albedo slot

REMEMBER: Unity has limited import options from Blender, so don't use any nodes or anything that's not basic. You'll have to do all that work in Unity since it's the engine that will render it all.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am still new at the whole Unity thing. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: You're welcome. If you think my answer explained how to do it or gave you information you feel is important to answer your question, please consider marking it as the selected answer.